# extracting row from CSV file with Python / Django

Tags: python

hey I'm trying to extract certain row from a CSV file with content in this form:

```
POS,Transaction id,Product,Quantity,Customer,Date
1,E100,TV,1,Test Customer,2022-09-19
2,E100,Laptop,3,Test Customer,2022-09-20
3,E200,TV,1,Test Customer,2022-09-21
4,E300,Smartphone,2,Test Customer,2022-09-22
5,E300,Laptop,5,New Customer,2022-09-23
6,E300,TV,1,New Customer,2022-09-23
7,E400,TV,2,ABC,2022-09-24
8,E500,Smartwatch,4,ABC,2022-09-25
```

the code I wrote is the following

```py
def csv_upload_view(request):
    print('file is being uploaded')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        csv_file = request.FILES.get('file')
        obj = CSV.objects.create(file_name=csv_file)

        with open(obj.file_name.path, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            reader.__next__()
            for  row in reader:
                data = "".join(row)
                data = data.split(";")
                #data.pop()
                print(data[0], type(data))
                transaction_id = data[0]
                product = data[1]
                quantity = int(data[2])
                customer = data[3]
                date = parse_date(data[4])
```

In the console then I get the following output:

```
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[22/Sep/2022 15:16:28] "GET /reports/from-file/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11719
file is being uploaded
1E100TV1Test Customer2022-09-19 <class 'list'>
```

So that I get the correct row put everything concatenated. If instead I put in a space in the **" ".join.row**  I get the entire row separated with empty spaces - what I would like to do is access this row with

```py
transaction_id = data[0]
                product = data[1]
                quantity = int(data[2])
                customer = data[3]
                date = parse_date(data[4])
```

but I always get an

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I also tried with data.replace(" ",";") but this gives me another error and the data type becomes a string instead of a list:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'E'
```

Can someone please show me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can split the rows (and find which row you want based on some provided value)

```py
with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',')

    line_count = 0

    for row in csv_reader:
        # Line 0 is the header

        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        
        else:
            line_count += 1
            # Here you can check if the row value is equal what you're finding
            # row[0] = POS
            # row[1] = Transaction id
            # row[2] = Product
            # row[3] = Quantity
            # row[4] = Customer
            # row[5] = Date

            if row[2] = "TV":
                #If you want to add all variables into a single string:
                data = ",".join(row) 

                # Make each row into a single variable:
                transaction_id = row[0]
                product = row[1]
                quantity = row[2]
                customer = row[3]
                date = row[4]
```

Comment: I think it's working now, need to check later with more time if everything works as intended but I can already access the items thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are joining/splitting the row up.  And you realize your split is using a semicolon?

I would expect something like this:

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

Transaction = namedtuple('Transaction', ['id', 'product', 'qty', 'customer', 'date'])

f_name = 'data.csv'
transactions = []  # to hold the result
with open(f_name, 'r') as src:
    src.readline()  # burn the header row
    reader = csv.reader(src)   # if you want to use csv reader
    for data in reader:
        #print(data)  <-- to see what the csv reader gives you...
        t = Transaction(data[1], data[2], int(data[3]), data[4], data[5])
        transactions.append(t)

for t in transactions:
    print(t)
```

The above "catches" results with a `namedtuple`, which is obviously optional.  You could put them in lists, etc.

Also `csv.reader` will do the splitting (by comma) by default.  I edited my previous answer.

As far as your question goes...  You mention extracting a "certain row" but you gave no indication how you would find such row.  If you know the row index/number, you could burn lines with `readline` or such, or just keep a counter while you read.  If you are looking for keyword in the data, just pop a conditional statement in either before or after splitting up the line.

Comment: thanks for your reply, just got back to my laptop, when I do this, I get an attribute error saying:  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip' after iterating through with 

for  row in reader:
                data = row.strip().split(',')
                print(data[0], type(data))

Comment: Yeah, I dorked that up.  I forgot that csv reader spits out lists and that is already done for you.  I usually don't use csv reader and DIY it, but reader is good.  Anyhow, answer has been modified above.

Comment: with data = str(row).strip().split(',') it actually works

Comment: well sure, but you are undoing what has already been done, which is nonsensical.  If you use csv reader, don't bother with that line....